# how to force restart activity from intent

Tags: android

My `MainActivity` has the `lauchMode="singleTask"`

Now I want to start the activity from a notification with special intent data.
in `MainActivity.onResume` I access the given intent data...

The problem is: When the activity already exists, and I click on the notification, the activity comes to foreground, but the method `onResume` is not called and I cannot access the intent data.

I tried the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and this works for Honeycomb but not for Gingerbread.

This is how I start the activity from a notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("triggerid", triggerid); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onResume()` is always called if the activity is not in the foreground.  However, what you're probably seeing is that `getIntent()` is returning the intent that started the activity, not the intent that was most recently sent to it.

To fix this, you should override `onNewIntent()`.  This will receive the new intent sent to it.  Then you can call `setIntent()` with the received intent, which will cause `getIntent()` to return the new intent when used in `onResume()`.