# When passing data between Activities with Intent Extra I keep getting the same value

Tags: android, android-intent

In my game I am trying to pass  the score from the PlayGame activity to the Scoreboard activity using an Intent Extra.
On finishing the game, I go to the scoreboard in  this way:

```
Intent intentScoreboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scoreboard.class);
intentScoreboard.putExtra("com.example.game.SCORE", score_counter);
startActivity(intentScoreboard);
```

and then in the Scoreboard class I retrieve it in the onResume() method like this:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int score = b.getInt("com.example.game.SCORE");
```

This works fine the first time, but if I then play another game and on finishing return to the scoreboard, I still get the score from the first game.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should use [Shared Preferences](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fcontent%2FSharedPreferences.html&ei=xB6MT8a2M47OrQel6bzDCw&usg=AFQjCNFyaMlF7pqBKbWPbXr7H1Wg4gKaoA&sig2=Ei4x9uRJNIar5_HYvdmL1A) for this purpose

Comment: I tried using Shared Preferences, but weirdly enough I have the same problem then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing calling setIntent()

Comment: if you call an Activity which already exist then it get on top or clear the activity stack as per flag attached to it. Now it works fine but the call to getIntent will always return the original intent. what you should do is in onNewInetent call setIntent(newIntent) then your code will work fine.. this is just my guess to your problem .

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I also had to add     intentScoreboard.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
let your score activity do a finish() if you get back to start a new game

then it should be working

Answer (score 0):

getIntent delivers the intent which started the activity. If the activity is resumed you get not the most recently received intent. See here for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838082/1127492

Comment: rather posting the same answer again i would prefer commenting on already posted one. this community works like this.

Comment: Sure, but when people are working asynchronously this happens w/o locking.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, see Javanator's answer above

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle` is not much needed to receive `getExtra()` values.
In my code, i have used to receive like this,

`int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("com.example.game.SCORE",defaultValue);`

It should works for your problem. And also it won't gives you the already received values.

Hope it sounds good for you dude.

Comment: No, I tried it, but to make that work i still need to call setIntent(). I like the shorter code, though :)

Comment: @muggezifter Actually it works fine with puExtra as String and getExtra as String. Try once with String values. Maybe you came to know the solution for Integer there too. Give it try instead of think of it dude. If you want the score to display only means (if you r not going to return this getExtra values and add or mult, any Integer operations) it may be fine to you to pass it as a String value right.